# Difference between lsof -c name and lsof | grep ^name?

Tags: linux, lsof

I'm trying to figure out whether I have a leak in file descriptors using **lsof**. The -c option to lsof is defined as:

- *Selects the listing of files for processes executing the command that begins with the characters of c.*

If that's true then why do these two commands report different numbers?

```
$ lsof -c gunicorn | wc -l
589
$ lsof | grep ^gunicorn | wc -l
29154
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at the lines and seeing what the difference is?

Comment: When I try this with a few different programs, the answers are only off by 1 (because the first command counts the heading line).

Comment: Are you sure you had the `^` character in the second command? If not, you'll match `gunicorn` anywhere on the line, not just the command name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `lsof` will output the the main process and the **threads** with a TID (Thread ID) However, if you if you filter the output using a `-c`, only process opened files are listed, without TID. You will notice this if you look at the headers of the two outputs, ´lsof -c´ output is missing the TID column.

You can read more about TID in the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html).